# How can I see my app bundles sales on iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect

On the last update of iTunes Connect you can create app bundles so you can sell several apps under sale price.

The problem is that I cannot figure out how can I track those sales. Seems that there is no way to see that from the website, Does anyone has a reference for a script or anything that could help monitor that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. it shows as a separate app sale (with the name of the app bundle) but only if there is one (under sales&trends).